# jammy failed to boot on HP laptop suddenly

Tags: boot, mount, 22.04

It looks like my dual boot laptop with win 10 and Ubuntu fails to boot today. I tried to repair the boot as well. Here are the logs before and after boot repairs. It still have same issue, after GNU grub boot selection if just keeps blinking.

### Before boot-repair logs:

Log file : [Before boot-repair logs](http://sprunge.us/jDS6YS)

### After Boot-repairs logs:

```
boot-repair-4ppa200                                              [20221108_2027]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================






Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
nvme0n1p5,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file


Mount nvme0n1p1 on /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/boot/efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p5/etc/default/grub

=============== Reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of nvme0n1p5 ===============

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5 modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5 efibootmgr -v before grub install
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,0001,0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,388339c1-b6e2-4054-800c-8e67ae6c41ee,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...o................
Boot0001* Solid State Disk  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0xe,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-1B-44-8B-48-19-74-69)/HD(1,GPT,388339c1-b6e2-4054-800c-8e67ae6c41ee,0x800,0x82000)..BO
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,388339c1-b6e2-4054-800c-8e67ae6c41ee,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0004* USB Drive (UEFI) -  USB   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(13,0)/USB(3,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x0,0x20,0x7298fe0)..BO

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5 uname -r
5.15.0-43-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5 efibootmgr -v after grub install
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,0001,0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,388339c1-b6e2-4054-800c-8e67ae6c41ee,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...o................
Boot0001* Solid State Disk  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0xe,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-1B-44-8B-48-19-74-69)/HD(1,GPT,388339c1-b6e2-4054-800c-8e67ae6c41ee,0x800,0x82000)..BO
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,388339c1-b6e2-4054-800c-8e67ae6c41ee,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0004* USB Drive (UEFI) -  USB   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(13,0)/USB(3,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x0,0x20,0x7298fe0)..BO
Warning: NVram was not modified.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-50-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p5/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04-4.07) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/HP/diw.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/BiosMgmt32.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/BiosMgmt.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/CryptRSA32.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/CryptRSA.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/HpBiosMgmt.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/HpBiosUpdate32.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/HpBiosUpdate.efi 
                       /efi/HP/SystemDiags/CryptRSA.efi 
                       /efi/HP/SystemDiags/diw.efi 
                       /efi/HP/SystemDiags/SysDiags.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.07 2013-07-25
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32864 of /dev/sda1 for its 
                       second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the /uui 
                       directory. The integrity check of the ADV area failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on nvme0n1p5
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: F.15(15.15) from AMI
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot enabled but mokutil says: SecureBoot enabled - Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com.
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,0001,0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,388339c1-b6e2-4054-800c-8e67ae6c41ee,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...o................
Boot0001* Solid State Disk  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0xe,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-1B-44-8B-48-19-74-69)/HD(1,GPT,388339c1-b6e2-4054-800c-8e67ae6c41ee,0x800,0x82000)..BO
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,388339c1-b6e2-4054-800c-8e67ae6c41ee,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0004* USB Drive (UEFI) -  USB   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(13,0)/USB(3,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x0,0x20,0x7298fe0)..BO

728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
c152ec201c37b6e97bbc2207e49d1271   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
3795ef72a4ed0369ca44e711527904bf   nvme0n1p1/Boot/grubx64.efi
fdafb5eece6caeccb788c946a28e6872   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
af7bce889aa877feb092ecfb1c5ba3a8   nvme0n1p1/HP/diw.efi
3795ef72a4ed0369ca44e711527904bf   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
fdafb5eece6caeccb788c946a28e6872   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
2c00d2225d10820a2b8fe32bd9dccbc7   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/BiosMgmt32.efi
09a4d4a2f9d161cf7a23755439eed58d   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/BiosMgmt.efi
1b8c0684ede8539ccc205cf7a750eca3   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/CryptRSA32.efi
6488d391f74263c9da3c3d47dffa6212   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/CryptRSA.efi
6d6c99b06136830bbc041fe57b04f658   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/HpBiosMgmt.efi
347b3ed013ebeaef3d7e2693229fe8dc   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/HpBiosUpdate32.efi
d723797e88d0b3b3a61a94146707a603   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/HpBiosUpdate.efi
6488d391f74263c9da3c3d47dffa6212   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/CryptRSA.efi
af7bce889aa877feb092ecfb1c5ba3a8   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/diw.efi
9ca774eb2290dce4f276eaec4aced423   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/SysDiags.efi
d1f6c29ed98f2a8102fd87c118371e0b   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
85b10a5efd8419adc616cb2a5a70db30   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p5   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 10ABEF42-04C6-4ACB-BE4E-36A8BB4E64FF
               Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
nvme0n1p2     534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3     567296  882361404  881794109 420.5G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 1999300608 2000396287    1095680   535M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5  882362368 1999300607 1116938240 532.6G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sda: 57.3 GiB, 61524148224 bytes, 120164352 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
      Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *       32 120164351 120164320 57.3G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:61.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos: USB  SanDisk 3.2Gen1:;
1:16.4kB:61.5GB:61.5GB:fat32::boot, lba;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:WDC PC SN530 SDBPNPZ-1T00-1006:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:452GB:451GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:452GB:1024GB:572GB:ext4::;
4:1024GB:1024GB:561MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL            PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                             
└─sda1      vfat     FDD6-F4AE                                                                 UUI              
nvme0n1                                                                                                         
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     5A9B-EC20                            388339c1-b6e2-4054-800c-8e67ae6c41ee SYSTEM           EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               d6ff2f04-ddd8-4dd8-997d-2ea0d991b761                  Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     D28EA5EB8EA5C875                     a85b31ed-d4ec-4e3e-9407-f52f04610767 Windows          Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     8ACC7DFECC7DE53B                     883df61c-609c-48ef-aa45-4fd5ec166735 Windows RE tools Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p5 ext4     d8fcd3a0-29f9-4daf-aea9-d00c18e73387 ee2eabc6-440f-4c30-947d-ac3e238017df                  

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1         164.3M  36% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3         178.4G  58% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4          66.9M  87% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5         365.7G  25% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/sda1               53.7G   6% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1         vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p3         fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p4         fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p5         ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda1              vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid d8fcd3a0-29f9-4daf-aea9-d00c18e73387 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   d8fcd3a0-29f9-4daf-aea9-d00c18e73387
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-52-generic   d8fcd3a0-29f9-4daf-aea9-d00c18e73387
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-50-generic   d8fcd3a0-29f9-4daf-aea9-d00c18e73387
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-5A9B-EC20
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p5/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=d8fcd3a0-29f9-4daf-aea9-d00c18e73387 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=5A9B-EC20  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme0n1p5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p5: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 705.183601379 = 757.185126400  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 689.688472748 = 740.547358720  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-50-generic                 2
 705.183601379 = 757.185126400  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic                 1
 689.688472748 = 740.547358720  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 745.836910248 = 800.836284416  boot/initrd.img                                5
 533.677162170 = 573.031489536  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic              2
 745.836910248 = 800.836284416  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic              5
 533.677162170 = 573.031489536  boot/initrd.img.old                            2

=================== nvme0n1p5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Mar 25  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Mar 30  2021 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 Mar 25  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Mar 25  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Mar 25  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb  8  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Oct  1  2020 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Mar 25  2022 41_custom

======================== nvme0n1p5/etc/grub.d/35_fwupd =========================

#! /bin/sh
# SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
set -e
[ -d ${pkgdatadir:?} ]
# shellcheck source=/dev/null
. "$pkgdatadir/grub-mkconfig_lib"
if [ -f /var/lib/fwupd/uefi_capsule.conf ] &&
   ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/fwupd-*-0abba7dc-e516-4167-bbf5-4d9d1c739416 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
      . /var/lib/fwupd/uefi_capsule.conf
      if [ "${EFI_PATH}" != "" ] && [ "${ESP}" != "" ]; then
      echo "Adding Linux Firmware Updater entry" >&2
cat << EOF
menuentry 'Linux Firmware Updater' \$menuentry_id_option 'fwupd' {
EOF
      ${grub_probe:?}
      prepare_grub_to_access_device '`${grub_probe} --target=device \${ESP}` | sed -e "s/^/\t/"'
cat << EOF
    chainloader ${EFI_PATH}
}
EOF
      fi
fi

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
paste.ubuntu.com ko ()
paste.debian.net ko (https://paste.debian.net/)
```

Any suggestions ? I had tried ubuntu recovery mode and try update and upgrade as well everything goes well. It looks like in snapd services failed somehow, i re-enable them as well still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Possible a memory error.

Check by:

- memtest
- memtest86
- memtest86+